# using Wordnet with stanford nlp

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, wordnet

I'm trying to get WordnetSynAnnotation of a token, it always returns null.

I'm not sure what I'm missing, is there an annotator for WordnetSynAnnotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to be set by any annotator in the code currently. A code search suggests that it was used in the NER system at one point, but is no longer set by anything.